# Check if entry in table A exists in table B

Tags: sql, exists

I have a definition table that I know is not being maintained very well, let's call this `table A`. I have another table (call it `table B`) that is much smaller and ideally should be a `subset of table A` but I know that `table A` is somewhat stale and does not contain new entries that are in `Table B`.

Note, that tables A and B have different columns.

```
Table A:
ID, Name, blah, blah, blah, blah

Table B:
ID, Name
```

I want all rows in Table B such that the ID in Table B does NOT exist in Table A. This does not just match rows in Table A; I want only rows in Table B where the ID does NOT exist at all in Table A.

Answer (score 216, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM   B
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                   FROM   A 
                   WHERE  A.ID = B.ID)
```

Comment: `select * from TableB b where b.ID not in (select a.ID from TableA a)`

Comment: @vakio Thanks for the query. You should definitely put your comment as an answer.

Comment: @AnalyticalMonk I hope you are aware it's exactly the same query which wield yield exactly the same results. Just a **slightly** different syntax, that's all

Comment: @gdoron I do realize that. However, I prefer this syntax despite the difference being minor. I apologize if my suggestion goes against SO policy.

Comment: @AnalyticalMonk no need to apologize, you did nothing wrong. I still think he made the right call not posting it as a different answer since it's basically the same. Good day sir.

Comment: can you ellaborate on what is select 1?

Comment: @ManosKounelakis `Select 1` means return `1` as the result for each row. It is often used to notate that the results don't matter but the existence alone is the one that matters. You can change `1` to every valid value (*, 1,2,3, column1, column2) and the results won't change.

Answer (score 42):

The classical answer that works in almost every environment is

```
SELECT ID, Name, blah, blah
FROM TableB TB
LEFT JOIN TableA TA
ON TB.ID=TA.ID
WHERE TA.ID IS NULL
```

sometimes NOT EXISTS may be not implemented (not working).

Comment: this query is more efficient than SELECT * FROM   B WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM   A WHERE  A.ID = B.ID)

Comment: The DUAL is special one row, one column table present by default in all Oracle databases. The owner of DUAL is SYS (SYS owns the data dictionary, therefore DUAL is part of the data dictionary.) but DUAL can be accessed by every user. The table has a single VARCHAR2(1) column called DUMMY that has a value of 'X'. MySQL allows DUAL to be specified as a table in queries that do not need data from any tables. In SQL Server DUAL table does not exist, but you could create one.

Comment: Faster than NOT EXISTS

Answer (score 15):

If you are set on using EXISTS you can use the below in SQL Server:

```
SELECT * FROM TableB as b
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
   SELECT * FROM TableA as a
   WHERE b.id = a.id
)
```

Answer (score 11):

This also works

```
SELECT *
FROM tableB
WHERE ID NOT IN (
  SELECT ID FROM tableA
);
```

Comment: I liked this one! Very straight forward and easy to grasp

Comment: This is the most simple and efficient answer for my case. I just wanted to check for existence of an id in another table one time for all rows.

Answer (score 0):

Or if "NOT EXISTS" are not implemented

```
SELECT *
FROM   B
WHERE (SELECT count(*)  FROM   A WHERE  A.ID = B.ID) < 1
```