# MySQL check if data exist

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have 2 tables namely nobio and registered2010. I want to check if fullname in table nobio exist in table registered2010. I don't what query should I use. I only want to check is if the data exist.

I used this query code.

```
  $query = "SELECT * FROM registered2010 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM nobio)";
```

Comment: Please improve your question. Add the table structures and add what you tried so far. Just for directions, you need a type of `JOIN`

Comment: Show the ddl, sample data the requested result and what you have tried.

Comment: possible duplicate of [sql: check if entry in table A exists in table B](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15938180/sql-check-if-entry-in-table-a-exists-in-table-b)

Comment: please add proper question, i have tried reading it but unable to understand your desired output.

Comment: @AmitShah already edited my question. I'm not so good in english.

Comment: @mar please have a look at answer now, and let me know if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this,

1) This query will give you all data where full name of registerted2010 table exists in nobio table.

```
  $query = "SELECT * FROM registered2010 WHERE fullname IN (SELECT fullname FROM nobio)";
```

2) This query will give you all data where full name of registerted2010 table do not exists in nobio table.

```
  $query = "SELECT * FROM registered2010 WHERE fullname NOT IN (SELECT fullname FROM nobio)";
```

Let me know if you want more help.

Thanks
Amit