# SQL: Check if entry exists in one table to another and remove duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The same question actually as this one: 
[sql: check if entry in table A exists in table B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15938180/sql-check-if-entry-in-table-a-exists-in-table-b)

Here are my tables, Employee and User

```
Employee           User
EmpNo              EmpNo
PositionCode
```

I just want to check if the EmpNo in table:Employee already exists in table:User
here's the code that ive used:

```
SELECT Employee.EmpNo, PositionCode
FROM   Employee
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                   FROM   User
                   WHERE  User.EmpNo= Employee.EmpNo)
```

Now with that query it displays the result,
But it also displays duplicate rows of PositionCode.

eg:

```
EmpNo    PositionCode 
E098     ER1
E712     ER1
E990     ER1
```

So yeah, I just need to get the PositionCode(in this ex its ER1) so I can display it to a dropdownList, and you dont want to display same items in a dropdownlist right?

Comment: Specify the expected result as well.

Comment: Specify data u have and expected result

Comment: If you dont want the related employees and only `Distinct` PositionCode you can just select `DISTINCT PositionCode` and that will give you the required output. It will be good if you  post expected result as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am still not sure what you want. But from my understanding you want distinct `PositionCode` which have `EmpNo` related to them. If that's what you want you can just select `Distinct PositionCode` as below.

```
SELECT DISTINCT PositionCode
FROM   Employee
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                   FROM   User
                   WHERE  User.EmpNo= Employee.EmpNo)
```

Let me know if this is not what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi, I have edited the question hope it will be clearer this time. Iam thinking of using the DISTINCT, but im not sure, the distinct wont affect my query of comparing the EmpNo on the two tables right? I mean EmpNo will still be validated if its not existing in the other table and will not show distinct results?

Comment: Distinct will apply after the filter happens on the tables. So it will only give you distinct rows with `PositionCode`.

Comment: hi @wolfQueen can u explain why u gave downvote to my answer
i posted as earlier as u accepted answer

Comment: @wolfQueen then give upvote because i posted answer earlier than u accepted answer

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT distinct  PositionCode
FROM   Employee
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                   FROM   User
                   WHERE  User.EmpNo= Employee.EmpNo)
```

Comment: Although this might solve the problem, it is always good to add an explanation why/how this works.