# SQL constraint check if entry in another table

Tags: sql, sqlite, constraints

Based on an integer ID, how can one constrain two tables referencing a common table from including the same element already in the other table?

A basic table of, let's say personal information is created:

```
CREATE TABLE person (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    info VARCHAR(10)
);
```

Then two tables referencing `person` is created:

```
CREATE TABLE special (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    skill VARCHAR(10),
    FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES person(id)
);

CREATE TABLE snowflake (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    meltingpoint DECIMAL,
    FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES person(id)
);
```

However, I want to constrain the two tables from including the same person.

So I thought something like this would do the trick, but SQLite3 gives syntax errors (near CHECK).

```
ALTER TABLE special ADD CHECK (
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM snowflake WHERE snowflake.id = special.id) = 0
);
```

OR based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15938180/sql-check-if-entry-in-table-a-exists-in-table-b)

```
ALTER TABLE special ADD CHECK (
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM snowflake WHERE snowflake.ID = special.ID)
);
```

How might this be achieved? Am I onto something or should an entirely different approach be taken?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#ckconst) says:

> The expression of a CHECK constraint may not contain a subquery.

So you have to use [trigger](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html)s:

```
CREATE TRIGGER no_snowflake_if_special
AFTER INSERT ON snowflake
WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM special WHERE id = NEW.id)
BEGIN
    SELECT RAISE(FAIL, "a special with the same ID already exists");
END;

-- same for special
```

Comment: Thank you! What is this `NEW`? Is it necessary (contrasting `special.id = id`)? Is it a handle to the inserted tuple (one would assume so..)?

Comment: Yes; see the linked documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You could have two foreign keys in 'person' to both 'special' and 'snowflake' and a check that only one of the keys has a value. Another solution could be to join 'special' and 'snowflake' into one table and have a check that only one of 'skill' or 'meltingpoint' is given.

Comment: So `CHECK` cannot reference another table for example?

Comment: @Felix Nope, not out of the box

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use **`ALTER TABLE`** to add a **CHECK** to a column.

You can only use **`ALTER TABLE`** to **`ADD`** a column which can then have a **`CHECK`** constraint. 
You cannot rename a column nor delete a column.

The easiest method would be to define the CHECK in the column when creating the table. If you have data that needs to be kept, then you will have to :-

- 1)create a new table,
- 2) copy the data from the original to the new table,
- 3) rename/drop the original and
- 4) rename the new table to the name of the original table.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/fi-fi/library/ms179491(v=sql.105).aspx here a `CHECK` is added after the creation of a table, is this only in SQLite that I can't do that?

Comment: Also, I can't really define both when creating tables since one of the two referencing tables has not yet been created. So at least one constraint has to be added after.

Comment: SQLite's ALTER is as I answered. See [ALTER TABLE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html). However, you will also see, as per [SQL Data Constraints](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#ckconst) that *The expression of a CHECK constraint may not contain a subquery.*