# Efficient way to verify a table is a subset of another table

Tags: sql

I have two tables A and B, the structures are exactly the same. I need to verify A is a subset of B. Because the structure contains over 100 fields, I do not want to list them one by one in a where predicates.

I would like to know if there is any more easier way to do that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sql: check if entry in table A exists in table B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15938180/sql-check-if-entry-in-table-a-exists-in-table-b)

Comment: I think you could do a UNION of tables A and B, then UNIQUE. If the COUNT of the result is the same as the count on A then there can't be any rows in A that aren't in B

Comment: You may consider to write storedProcedure with dynamic SQL using Information schemas.

Comment: @robertoplancarte, this works if table A does not have duplicate records. you need to distinctify both sides

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@robertoplancarte's approach with little tweaking

```
with tB_cnt as 
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT * FROM dbo.T_B 
    ) T_B
), TAB_cnt as 
(
    SELECT count(*) cnt FROM 
    (
        SELECT * FROM dto.T_B
        UNION
        SELECT * FROM dto.T_A          
    ) T_AB
)
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN TB_CNT.CNT = TAB_CNT.CNT THEN 
    'Table A is subset of B' 
  else 
    'Table A is not subset of B' 
  END as Result
FROM TAB_CNT, TB_CNT
```

Comment: UNION already removes duplicates. The DISTINCT is thus redundant.

Comment: I also think you may have meant INTERSECT rather than UNION

Comment: if T_A has 500 rows and T_B has 300 rows same as A, union will return 500 rows for T_A which we conclude that T_B is subset of T_A because result count remained same. isn't it?

Comment: i see what you mean. I mis-understand the question. Fixed the approach

Comment: Union works, if you change your output messages.  Your code and your comment aren't the same.

Comment: This now appears to work. But why it's preferred to EXCEPT I have no idea.

Comment: Does it not need the same assumption that there are no duplicates in A? It's showing me that A is subset of B even though A has a duplicate row that exists in B only once.

Comment: Yes, exactly the same behaviour as EXCEPT.

Comment: Just for the record, I did not downvote this answer.

Comment: @KamilGosciminski I believe in the SET approach there is no duplication case in math? I am not sure just asking. But If we really need to consider dublicate records, I can use UNION ALL approach with no DISTINCT clause. But It seems that this answer is enough for him. Thank you for supporting my answer by not downvoting :)

Comment: @Simonare that is true however as MatBailie pointed out, SQL is not all about Set Theory, so duplicates can happen. Regarding your mentioned approach, this will almost never work, as sum of rows A+B can never equal number of rows in B unless A is empty.

Comment: Fair, then we need more complex approach for duplicates to work. In match we need  A U B - B + A ∩ B. Bit if we use minus and intersect it will remote dublicates. anyway SQL is not all about Set operations as it is stated. I am very glad that you put considerable time to this conversation. Thank you

Answer (score 8):

**Assumptions**:

**(1)** Identical table structure of `A` and `B`. This means that both order of columns and their data types have to match.

**(2)** There are no duplicate rows in table `A`

**Problem description**

To prove that `A is a subset of B` you need to show that `A\B = empty set`.

**Solution**

This means that if you remove every row in `A` that has a matching row in `B` and your output is empty (0 rows) this means that `A is subset of B`.

If on the other hand, in the output you get `> 0` rows it means that `A` has rows that `B` doesnt and that `A isn't a subset of B`.

```
SELECT * FROM A
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM B
```

When `A` is empty (contains 0 rows) it will be treated as a subset of `B`, because the result of above query will be 0 rows.

Comment: That's predicated on the idea that all the rows are universally unique. If A has two rows that are exact duplicates, then B only needs one such row to cause EXCEPT to return zero rows.

Comment: If we're talking about Set Theory then no duplicates are allowed, but indeed, you are right, that this might be the issue if the table allows data duplicates. I will include that as an assumption. For this case we would need a bit more complicated piece of code. Good point!

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. The main problem here, if we would like to take duplicates into account is that we're basing on set operators. I believe this is not possible to solve (with duplicate data) using set operators only and not minding columns at all. I see no way of determining which records are duplicates. There might be: a duplicate in A but then again a duplicate of different row in B.

Comment: The solution is to add a derived column that causes all rows to be unique. For example, if the tables have three columns you might add `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a, b, c ORDER BY NULL) AS differentiator`(or similar) to both tables, then apply the EXCEPT method.

Comment: Thought about it, but that violates not mentioning columns in the code, as we might need all of those 100 OP mentioned. It isn't hard for one query though and I'd definitely go for it.

Comment: Doesn't `EXCEPT ALL` which PostgreSQL has helps here with duplicates?