# Oracle APex change button in column based on condition

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have an IG with a column called Validated.

IG Query:

```
select validated, emp_id, emp_name, emp_designation,emp_hier from employees;
```

I have another table:

```
select  emp_id, emp_name, emp_designation,emp_hier from employee_admin;
```

I need to compare both tables and if

```
select  emp_id, emp_name, emp_designation,emp_hier from employees;
minus
select  emp_id, emp_name, emp_designation,emp_hier from employee_admin;
```

returns 0 rows, then the button colour should be green else red.

Validated is a link column.

I have a VALID_BUT hidden column as well which is linked to the link column using Link attributes :

```
class="&VALID_BUT"
```

Where and how can i add condition so that the button changes colours?

Answer (score 2):

On your IG's initialisation code:

```
function(options) {
    options.defaultGridColumnOptions = {
        cellCssClassesColumn:"virtual_color_column"
    }
    return options;
}
```

Then on your IG, create a new virtual column named 'virtual_color_column'. As the source of this column, use:

```
declare
  v_count number;
begin
  --add your where conditions to the query accordingly
  select count(1)
  into v_count
  from employees 
  where emp_id not in (select emp_id from employee_admin);

  select 
    case when v_count > 0 then 'RED' 
      else 'GREEN' 
    end as virtual_color_column 
  from dual;
end;
```

And lastly, on your page's inline CSS section, define the classes:

```
.RED{ 
    background-color: red;
}

.GREEN{ 
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. In SQL query i need to compare all columns. Is there any other way to compare all columns at once?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43242534/8130251 check this answer or other answers to the same questions please.